# Do we have temperature sensor in windows phone 7?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, sensors

Do we have temperature sensor in windows phone 7 That notes the Outside Atmospheric Temperature.

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Surely that depends on what phone you have and not the OS?

Comment: A wee bit of logical thinking could answer that question.  Crotch temperature is around 37 Celsius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no temperature API. (I assume you want to access it programmatically). An alternative could be to get the user's GPS location and use an online weather API to get the temperature for their location.

Comment: I'm in a situation where I need to get the room temperature. Like when the user is in the room with heater or AC switched on.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way of detecting that from your app.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you can't. The windows phone doesn't support thermal detection feature. Sadly there is no alternative available for u to satisfy your requirement.